# Display score in TextView in android?

Tags: java, android, scoring

I am working on android quiz. I have **setQuestion()** method in **QuestionActivity** class. I have question.xml in which i create **TextView** to show scores. I want to write code in setQuestion so that its set TextView of that button with score.Basically my scores are retrieving from getScore() method in GamePlay class and scores updated with right or wrong answer. like in setQuestion() method my next question answer TextView updated on next round.

```
public class GamePlay {

    private int numRounds;
    private int difficulty;
    private int score;
    private int round;

    private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();


    /**
     * @return the right
     */
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    /**
     * @param right the right to set
     */
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    /**
     * @return the round
     */
    public int getRound() {
        return round;
    }
    /**
     * @param round the round to set
     */
    public void setRound(int round) {
        this.round = round;
    }
    /**
     * @param difficulty the difficulty to set
     */
    public void setDifficulty(int difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }
    /**
     * @return the difficulty
     */
    public int getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }
    /**
     * @param questions the questions to set
     */
    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }

    /**
     * @param q the question to add
     */
    public void addQuestions(Question q) {
        this.questions.add(q);
    }

    /**
     * @return the questions
     */
    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }


    public Question getNextQuestion(){

        //get the question
        Question next = questions.get(this.getRound());
        //update the round number to the next round
        this.setRound(this.getRound()+1);
        return next;
    }

    /**
     * method to increment the number of correct answers this game
     */


    /**
     * method to increment the number of incorrect answers this game
     */
    public void incrementScore(){
        score=score+100;
    }

    public void decrementScore()
    {
        score=score-50;
    }
    /**
     * @param numRounds the numRounds to set
     */
    public void setNumRounds(int numRounds) {
        this.numRounds = numRounds;
    }
    /**
     * @return the numRounds
     */
    public int getNumRounds() {
        return numRounds;
    }

    /**
     * method that checks if the game is over
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean isGameOver(){
        return (getRound() >= getNumRounds());
    }


}







public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Question currentQ;
    private GamePlay currentGame;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);
        /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
        currentGame = ((ABCApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
        Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();

    }


    /**
     * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
     * current question
     */
    private void setQuestions() {
        //set the question text from current question
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);

        //set the available options
        List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));

        TextView score1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        setText score1=GamePlay.getScore();       
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
    if(!checkAnswer(arg0)) return;  

        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()){
            //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
            Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /**
     * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
     * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
     */
    private boolean checkAnswer(View v) {

        Button b=(Button) v;
        String answer = b.getText().toString();

            //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
            if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
            {
                //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
                currentGame.incrementScore();
            }
            else{
                //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
                currentGame.decrementScore();
            }
            return true;
        }








question.xml

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/score_img"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should check by this:

```
 int score = currentGame.getScore(); ;
```

and then convert it to STring

```
 String scr = String.valueOf(score);
```

then set to TextView

```
 TextView score1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
 score1.setText(scr);
```

ok..

Comment: its showing error. and solution is to make getScore() method static. but if i make that method static its show error in returning value.

Comment: i have one more question in my quiz game i want to add timer on my first question and next questions. i want this timer triggered when i click on play button. is it possible to do?

Comment: bro. you can check code on this link if you able to solve it plz help me.                                                                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614963/how-to-trigger-timer-from-other-class-and-its-textview-and-implementation-in-ano

Comment: you checked that link? Is there any problem?