# how to trigger timer from other class and its TextView and implementation in another xml and class respectively?

Tags: java, android, xml, timer

I am working on android quiz and want timer on my each question-answer page. I have menu page in my quiz and play button to start game. And i want this timer is triggered when i click on play button. For this i have to create TextView in question XML that represent my menu page. And implementation in QuestionActivity class which represent my first question page. i am also posting WelcomeActivity class although its not play any role in this question.

**Play Button Layout**

```
<Button 
            android:text="Play" 
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_width="80dip" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dip" 
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="@drawable/start_button" />
```

**Question XML representing TextView for Timer**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/question"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/timer_bttn" 
    android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

**QuestionActivity where i implemented timer code**

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Question currentQ;
    private GamePlay currentGame;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.question);
        /**
         * Configure current game and get question
         */
        currentGame = ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).getCurrentGame();
        currentQ = currentGame.getNextQuestion();
        Button nextBtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        nextBtn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        nextBtn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        nextBtn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button nextBtn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        nextBtn4.setOnClickListener(this);
        /**
         * Update the question and answer options..
         */
        setQuestions();

    }


    /**
     * Method to set the text for the question and answers from the current games
     * current question
     */
    private void setQuestions() {
        //set the question text from current question
        String question = Utility.capitalise(currentQ.getQuestion());
        TextView qText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        qText.setText(question);

        //set the available options
        List<String> answers = currentQ.getQuestionOptions();
        TextView option1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        option1.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(0)));

        TextView option2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        option2.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(1)));

        TextView option3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        option3.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(2)));

        TextView option4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer4);
        option4.setText(Utility.capitalise(answers.get(3)));

        int score = currentGame.getScore();
        String scr = String.valueOf(score);
        TextView score1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        score1.setText(scr);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Moving to next question");
        if(!checkAnswer(arg0)) return;  

        /**
         * check if end of game
         */
        if (currentGame.isGameOver()) {
            //Log.d("Questions", "End of game! lets add up the scores..");
            //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Correct: " + currentGame.getRight());
        //Log.d("Questions", "Questions Wrong: " + currentGame.getWrong());
        Intent i = new Intent(this, EndgameActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        }
        else {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK :
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /**
     * Check if a checkbox has been selected, and if it
     * has then check if its correct and update gamescore
     */
    private boolean checkAnswer(View v) {

        Button b=(Button) v;
        String answer = b.getText().toString();

        //Log.d("Questions", "Valid Checkbox selection made - check if correct");
        if (currentQ.getAnswer().equalsIgnoreCase(answer))
        {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Correct Answer!");
        currentGame.incrementScore();
        }
        else {
        //Log.d("Questions", "Incorrect Answer!");
        currentGame.decrementScore();
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void setTimer() {
        long finishTime = 5;
        CountDownTimer counterTimer = new CountDownTimer(finishTime * 1000, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {
                //code to execute when time finished
            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                int minutes = seconds / 60;
                seconds = seconds % 60;

                if (seconds < 10) {
                    txtTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
                } else {
                    txtTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                }
            }
        };
        counterTimer.start();
    }

}
```

**WelcomeActivity**

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////// GAME MENU  /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Button playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);
    playBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button settingsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsBtn);
    settingsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button rulesBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rulesBtn);
    rulesBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button exitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
    exitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}


/**
 * Listener for game menu
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i;

    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.playBtn :
        //once logged in, load the main page
        //Log.d("LOGIN", "User has started the game");

        //Get Question set //
        List<Question> questions = getQuestionSetFromDb();

        //Initialise Game with retrieved question set ///
        GamePlay c = new GamePlay();
        c.setQuestions(questions);
        c.setNumRounds(getNumQuestions());
        ((CYKApplication)getApplication()).setCurrentGame(c);  

        //Start Game Now.. //
        i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.PLAYBUTTON);
        break;

    case R.id.rulesBtn :
        i = new Intent(this, RulesActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.RULESBUTTON);
        break;

    case R.id.settingsBtn :
        i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, Constants.SETTINGSBUTTON);
        break;

    case R.id.exitBtn :
        finish();
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: trigger your timer in `onResume` in QuestionActivity

Comment: i am not getting your answer. can you explain it with some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Piyush Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1844392/piyush-gupta), you should call the `setTimer()` method from `onResume` in your `QuestionActivity`.

From the [Android Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29):

`(onResume is) called for your activity to start interacting with the user. This is a good place to begin animations, open exclusive-access devices (such as the camera), etc.`

In your code you should also make the `counterTimer` you use in `setTimer()` a **class member**, not a local variable; if you don't it will go out of scope once the `setTimer()` call completes and your access to it will be lost.

So you will need to add the following to `QuestionActivity`:

```
public class QuestionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    // NEW: add counterTimer as a member
    private CountDownTimer counterTimer;

    // NEW: implement onResume
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        setTimer();
        super.onResume();
    }

    // CHANGE: setTimer should be changed as follows
    public void setTimer() {
        long finishTime = 5;
        // NOTE: use the member, instead of a local
        counterTimer = new CountDownTimer(finishTime * 1000, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {
                //code to execute when time finished
            }

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                int minutes = seconds / 60;
                seconds = seconds % 60;

                if (seconds < 10) {
                    txtTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":0" + seconds);
                } else {
                    txtTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
                }
            }
        };
        counterTimer.start();
    }
}
```

This above example uses your code as it is now, but I would advise you to create the timer in `onCreate` using the class member to store it (ie. everything that is currently in setTimer(), except for the `counterTimer.start();` call. Then just use `counterTimer.start();` in `onResume`. And maybe add a `counterTimer.cancel()` call to `onPause` so that the timer ends when the activity loses focus.

Comment: as i want to decrease in score when times up for that i add call to currentGame.decrementScore() but instead of only decrementing scores on only time up its decreasing it in every round. Any solution?

Comment: Sure, just put that call in the `onFinish()` method of the `CountDownTimer`. Then just make sure to **stop** the timer when an answer is selected (so that the `onFinish()` is no longer called).

Comment: how to hold screen for few seconds if we click on a button?

Comment: I would stop the countdown timer (the one which is used for time remaining to answer), then use a **new** timer with the time you want to "hold" for, and in the new timer's `onFinish` you can then advance to the next screen/question.

Comment: ok i already done that. thank u for that. how to hold screen for few seconds when we prssed a button?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37046/discussion-between-john-r-and-free3dom)

Comment: @Will i want your views on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917620/how-to-create-log-in-page-in-android-app/18917744?noredirect=1#comment27930641_18917744 please check it.