# how to write code for dialog box when we click on exit and code for dialog xml in android?

Tags: android, xml, dialog, exit

i want to write code for dialog box in the following code when quit button is pressed its show message do you really want to exit if "yes" completly close the application page if no it come backs on the current page. i already use system.exit(0) but its close current activity and comes on menu page. so please write some code to completly terminate application. and for that dialog box i need to create new xml file?

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0.getId()==R.id.btnId)
        {
              //write code here 
        }
              }
```

here btnId is id of exit button. i have seen one answer related to back button with dialogue button on stackoverflow. but its slightly different then my code. so i am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps.

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(YOUR_ACTIVITY)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure?")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int id) {
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

        }
```

Comment: on the place of YOUR_ACTIVITY i have to write activity in which i am adding this code if yes. then its showing error on that line.

Comment: yes you should put your activity there. for example if you activity's name is MainActivity then you can put MainActivity.this

Comment: its working but when dialog box appears its remain visible for only one second. what is the way to hold it until we press yes or no.

Comment: hmm. it shouldn't happen actually. but try .setCancelable(false) istead of .setCancelable(true)

Comment: bro. its working. actually i have some problem in my code and now i solved it and your code working properly. its good answer.

Comment: i have one problem. if you like to help me then check out this link     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614963/how-to-trigger-timer-from-other-class-and-its-textview-and-implementation-in-ano

Comment: yes but couldn't spend time so much. i am working now. i'll try to look when i can find time

Comment: i want your views on this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917620/how-to-create-log-in-page-in-android-app/18917744?noredirect=1#comment27930641_18917744 please check it.

Answer (score 0):

for the dialog

try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
        ad.setCancelable(false);
        ad.setTitle("EXIT CONFIRMATION");
        ad.setMessage("are you sure you want to exit?");
        ad.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                finish();
            onDestroy();
            }
        });
        ad.show();
```

act in my code is activity or context

Answer (score 0):

To make a full dialog for the "Yes" and "No". Do the following:

Note: for this code you will need a button.

Hope it helps.

> Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Alert");
            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Do you really want to exit?");

            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            ad.setCancelable(false);
            ad.setTitle("EXIT CONFIRMATION");
            ad.setMessage("are you sure you want to exit?");
            ad.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    finish();



                }
            });
            ad.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     dialog.cancel();
                }
            }); 

            ad.show();

          }
        });
```